# Android Studio confusing between my projects, not able to switch seamlessly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I have 2 completely separate working copies of the same project, just 2 different git branches.

Opening one of them from scratch will result in a successful build.

However, if I open the other one after the previous one was used in Android Studio, Android Studio will fail miserably, trying to sync different gradle parts that belong to 2 different projects.

In order to switch between those projects, I have to kill \ restart Android Studio and open the project I want to work on - and even then, it's doing some heavy and unnecessary indexing and syncing just because of this switch.

I am looking for a way to fix this annoying issue, and make Android Studio really decouple 2 different and unrelated working copies - so I can switch between them quickly.

I am seriously considering using a VM to run different OS X images with Android Studio (I'm on MacOS High Sierra).

Comment: How is your projects folder structure?

Comment: @MatPag Completely normal, the same you would get if creating a new Android Studio project.
They are in 2 different, non-overlapping directories, and have no shared dependencies on the file system.

Comment: how you switch? Open new project in new window? Isn't it the expected behaviour? AFAIK Android studio can't have 2 project opened in single project structure like eclipse.

Comment: @MatPag I open a project in a new window. No, the expected behavior would be that Android Studio treat my other working copy as something unrelated to the 1st working copy. Why does it have to do more indexing / syncing passes, or fail because of mixing gradle scripts from before? It's probably some internal cache bug in Android Studio. Both of those working copies build successfully, and can be re-opened seamlessly - if the other one is not touched.

Comment: @SirKnigget so they have 2 different .idea folders (one for each projects)? Is one project directory inside the other? Which version of Studio are you running?

Comment: @MatPag Yes, and no. They are absolutely unrelated, 2 different directories and 2 different .idea folders. Android Studio 3.1.3.

Comment: @SirKnigget This is how i'm working with multiple projects. Open the first project, then instead of closing it go in File -> Open Recent -> open the other project. The indexing and syncing will last only few seconds and you can switch between projects without reloading everytime the Studio window.

Comment: @MatPag That's exactly what I'm doing. It doesn't work like you describe. It fails to build and I have to kill and restart, and then it does a lot of indexing / re-syncing.

Comment: @SirKnigget Ok, so let's try to Invalidate cache and restart in both projects to see if it helps. Go to File -> Invalidate caches / restart -> Invalidate and restart

Comment: @MatPag I already did that. This is exactly what I wish to avoid having to do when switching.

Comment: @SirKnigget have you tried to upgrade AS to latest 3.1.4 version?

Comment: @MatPag No change after update.